# bar button is not showing on the navigation bar at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2), and as shown in image-1 below, I added the "Add" bar button, but when I run the simulator it does not show up as shown in image-2.

please let me know why the "Add" button is not showing and how to fix it.

**image-1**:

[image]

**image-2**:

[image]

Comment: are you added the navigation bar manually

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes i added it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible scenario :

**Scene 1 :**

Looks like you are using iPhone 6s Plus simulator and 100% zoomed. So I could see horizontal and vertical scroll both. I believe the Plus button is still there its just that u have to scroll to see it. Even the title Players is not in center :)

Use Command + 3 to zoom out the simulator and see the O/P without scroll :D

**Scene 2:**

If you have added Navigation bar manually make sure you add top, leading and trailing constraint to Navigation Bar. The Nav bar you added is bigger than iPhone 6 plus size and because there is no auto layout constraint added it might have extended beyond the screen.

[image]